# Facebook Login SDK returns to the app without authorizing app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement facebook login using native iOS SDK. I'm following their Session Login Sample code, but when I press the facebook login button, facebook login page pops up. Right after entering username and password, it will switch back to my app (without going through app authorization) and my Session is still closed.

What would be the possible issue?

Comment: did u set up  "FacebookDisplayName","FacebookAppID","URL types" ... ?

Comment: Yes, all in the Plist file.

URl Schemes :fb+my FB App ID >> ex: fb1234567890102

Answer (score 0):

A very common issue is having 2 app on your device with the same facebook url Scheme.
After login, facebook try to re-open your app using the facebook urlScheme, but if you have 2 (or more) app with this url scheme, another one can be open.
Happen to me a lot of time when I have the same app installed with different bundle ids (debug / release for exemple)

Comment: I tried to reset the Simulator. but its still the same!! Don't you think there is something wrong with my facebook app?

Comment: How do you test that your session is closed ?

Comment: if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) { }
There is only one app in my simulator!

Comment: Do you give a completionHandler to the open method ? If Yes, is it called ? If no, you should add one.
Second thought, you can get your active session this way :
`[FBSession activeSession].isOpen` (just remember to do this when you create it the first time : `[FBSession setActiveSession:session];`) I think that is a better way to manage it that setting it as a property of your appDelegate. You should give it a try.